# How to create plugin for observer magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

I want to create Plugin for observer `SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver`, I created a `di.xml` file and added below coded,

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver">
    <plugin name="NameSpace_SalesRule::SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver" type=" NameSpace\SalesRule\Plugin\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserverPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

And Created `SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserverPlugin.php` plugin File,

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\SalesRule\Plugin\Observer;

use Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserverPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver $subject
     * @param                              $result
     * @param EventObserver                $observer
     */
    public function afterExecute(SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver $subject, $result, EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

    }
}
```

But My Plugin is not calling.

Does have any idea?

Comment: There is a space in the type declaration attribute. Is this a typo here or is it also in your source code?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this updated code:

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver">
      <plugin name="NameSpace_SalesRule::SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver" type="NameSpace\SalesRule\Plugin\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserverPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

**SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserverPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\SalesRule\Plugin\Observer;

use Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserverPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver $subject
     * @param                              $result
     * @param EventObserver                $observer
     */
    public function afterExecute(SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver $subject, $result, EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

    }
}
```